# WingIDE C:\Python27 __init__.py" raise CodecRegistryError SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm

I had a program that ran successfully in `PyCharm`. I then just installed `Wing IDE` and tried to run that same program, but now I get the error

```
C:\Python27\Lib\encodings\__init__.py", line 123

raise CodecRegistryError,\
                         ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 20):

This occurs because you have an environment variable that refer to another Python version which is not the version you're using right now.

This how to fix this issue:

In a terminal window (cmd.exe), try the this command:

```
set | findstr /i python
```

If you get an output like this, `Path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLSClient\;C:\csvn\bin\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system 32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin;C:\Apache\apache-ant-1.10.1\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;D:\Acedemic\Open Source Project\10.11\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Users\Rajitha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Users\Rajitha\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
PYTHONHOME=C:\csvn\Python25\*`

**Remove the "PYTHONHOME" environmental variable.**

If you get an output like this,`C:\Users\Acebulf>set | findstr /i python
Path=C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System2\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program
Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\1
10\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\;C:\Program Files\In
tel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Python27\
PYTHONPATH=C:\Python27\Lib;C:\Python27\DLLs;C:\Python27\Lib\lib-tk;`

**Remove the "PYTHONPATH" environmental variable.**

This should fix the error!

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me.
A note: After the above step, the command prompt has to be restarted (closed and open again)

Comment: removing the "PYTHONHOME" variable from environmental variable worked. I am using Windows 10. And somehow PYTHONHOME path was set to home directory of python 2.7. But I have Python 3.9 also installed.

Answer (score 1):

It may be because you have different versions of Python installed, and you are using one version's interpreter with another version's libraries.   If running under Windows, check your environment settings.

Comment: especially look at the `PYTHONPATH` variable - see https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/93 If it's set, try to unset it.