# Raw kernel process exited code: 3221226505

Tags: python, tensorflow

I was working on my notebook using visual studio code, and training the model for the X times felt long.

So I decided I should try train them using GPU instead of GPU.

I follow this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hHWkvEcDBO0

Which basically is very similar than what you can find in tensorflow docs.
You have to  :

1. Download and install Nvidia CUDA Toolkit (here 11.x)
2. Download cuDNN
3. Extract its content in the same folder as the CUDA Toolkit
4. Add 2 vars in the path variable.

After this operation, I restarted my computer and I was able to see my GPU when I was doing :

`print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')))`

Sadly every time a training or a predict cell was run, I was getting an error :

```
Canceled future for execute_request message before replies were done
```

I search into the logs to discover this :

```
warn 22:44:34.276: StdErr from Kernel Process 2022-10-03 22:44:34.276506: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:384] Loaded cuDNN version 8500

error 22:44:34.637: Disposing session as kernel process died ExitCode: 3221226505, Reason: c:\Users\Variraptor\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py:2196: FutureWarning: Supporting extra quotes around Unicode is deprecated in traitlets 5.0. Use 'hmac-sha256' instead of '"hmac-sha256"' – or use CUnicode.
  warn(
c:\Users\Variraptor\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py:2151: FutureWarning: Supporting extra quotes around Bytes is deprecated in traitlets 5.0. Use 'dd5c0f8d-3774-496a-930e-bf20e1603651' instead of 'b"dd5c0f8d-3774-496a-930e-bf20e1603651"'.
  warn(
2022-10-03 22:44:25.003727: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2022-10-03 22:44:25.604543: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1532] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 3962 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2060, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5
2022-10-03 22:44:34.276506: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:384] Loaded cuDNN version 8500

info 22:44:34.638: kill daemon
error 22:44:34.639: Raw kernel process exited code: 3221226505
error 22:44:34.640: Error in waiting for cell to complete [Error: Canceled future for execute_request message before replies were done
    at t.KernelShellFutureHandler.dispose (c:\Users\Variraptor\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.7.1102252217\out\extension.node.js:2:32353)
    at c:\Users\Variraptor\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.7.1102252217\out\extension.node.js:2:51405
    at Map.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at y._clearKernelState (c:\Users\Variraptor\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.7.1102252217\out\extension.node.js:2:51390)
    at y.dispose (c:\Users\Variraptor\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.7.1102252217\out\extension.node.js:2:44872)
    at c:\Users\Variraptor\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.7.1102252217\out\extension.node.js:2:2320921
    at t.swallowExceptions (c:\Users\Variraptor\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.7.1102252217\out\extension.node.js:7:118974)
    at dispose (c:\Users\Variraptor\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.7.1102252217\out\extension.node.js:2:2320899)
    at t.RawSession.dispose (c:\Users\Variraptor\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.7.1102252217\out\extension.node.js:2:2325836)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)]
warn 22:44:34.640: Cell completed with errors {
  message: 'Canceled future for execute_request message before replies were done'
}
info 22:44:34.642: Cancel all remaining cells true || Error || undefined
info 22:44:34.642: Cancel pending cells
info 22:44:34.642: Cell 8 executed with state Error
```

I tried to follow the answer from Nicola Manca, from another topic, but it doesn't seems to work with my problem.

Since it's my first step in GPU as a non native english student, I'm completely stuck.

Could you help me understanding the error here ?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue but my GPU installation was unsuccessful.
the issue is with the environment variables added once I deleted them, it's working for me.
-see this it may help you [WingIDE C:\Python27 __init__.py" raise CodecRegistryError SyntaxError: invalid syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29426962/wingide-c-python27-init-py-raise-codecregistryerror-syntaxerror-invalid-s)